# How to redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc website and I want users when write the URL as this https://example.com to automatically forward them to the http version of the same page to be http://example.com
Can this be done using mvc routing? or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Global.asax file try something like.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("https:", "http:"));
}
```